# Hexadecimal Convention in Memory

Tags: memory, hex, conventions, computation-theory, number-theory

a super stupid question:

I have an integer in my code, which occupies 4 bytes ( of course ), this information in memory is represented as a pack of four hexadecimal of two digits, for example

`int x = 1000`

in memory is represented as

`e8 03 00 00`

where the first hex represents the "lower" byte and the last is the "highest".
How is this representation called? Are there other representations? I just need the name. I'm struggling to find online this information :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is Endianness.